Voiceflow knowledge base document api - works from Insomnia, but not cURL
In VoiceFlow, I'm trying to incorporate programmatic knowledge updates via the knowledge documents API.
I have it working from the Insomnia app, but when I export Insomnia request to a cUrl command and run it, get an error.
Document and API key, which I've removed below, are correct, since they work from Insomnia.  I've verified that the file is in the current working folder in windows, which is where I am running cUrl from. Tried it both with url quoted and unquoted.  T
his is a Replace Document (non-url) api call.
doc
curl --request PUT 
     --url 'https://api.voiceflow.com/v3alpha/knowledge-base/docs/<document id>/upload?maxChunkSize=1000' 
     --header 'Authorization: <api key>' 
     --header 'accept: application/json' 
     --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data' 
     --form file='@Jaberwocky.txt'

Response:

curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: multipart

What is wrong with the curl command?
